# How parse a json data that has a dictionary key:value pair? I'm trying to extract the symbol and value pair

Tags: json, swift, parsing, nsdictionary

How to correctly parse the following json data?
My problem is at the line: `if let rates = data["rates"] as? NSDictionary...`

The json data

```
{   "valid": true,   
    "timestamp": 1579683079,   
    "base": "USD",  
    "rates": {
       "AED": 3.67316,
       "AFN": 77.99911,
       "ALL": 110.11741,
       ...
       "ZAR": 14.45,
       "ZMW": 14.63257   
     } 
 }
```

Code

```
import UIKit

struct CurrencyRate {
    var valid: String
    var timestamp: Int
    var base: String
    var rates: [String:Double] = [:]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var mySymbols:[String] = []
var myValues:[Double] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let jsonUrlString = "https://currencyapi.net/api/v1/rates?key=6b171cc58787d922eb53e3684d97784d165a&base=USD"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        if let rates = data["rates"] as? NSDictionary {
            for (key, value) in rates {
                self.mySymbols.append((key as? String)!)

                self.myValues.append((value as? Double)!)
            }
        }


    }.resume()

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NSDictionary` - use `Dictionary` type in Swift. Also, you have `data` and it's not dictionary at all. It's `Data` type. Use should convert your data to your type. Try use this code:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
    guard let data = data else { return }

    let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

    if let dict = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let rates = dict["rates"] as? Dictionary<String, Double> {
        for (key, value) in rates {
            print(key, value)
            self.mySymbols.append(key)
            self.myValues.append(value)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

There is a way with `Codable`, but I guess it will be the next challenge for you. Also, keep in mind that the code is executed asynchronously and the data in global variables will not appear immediately

Comment: Please don't suggest `.mutableContainers`.  It's useless in Swift and you are assigning the result to an immutable constant anyway.

Comment: Since Swift 3 you can even remove the entire `options` parameter, *no options* is the default.

Comment: Great! I've looked at the documentation - you're right, now I know that I can reduce the signature of this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
for (key, value) in ...
```

to enumerate a dictionary exists only for native Swift dictionaries.

This is supposed to work, if you cast to specific `[String:Double]` you even get rid of the ugly type cast of `key` and `value`.

```
if let rates = data["rates"] as? [String:Double] {
    for (key, value) in rates {
        self.mySymbols.append(key)
        self.myValues.append(value)
    }
}
```

However you are encouraged to use the `Decodable` protocol to parse the JSON. There are only a few slightly changes.

```
struct CurrencyRate : Decodable {
    let valid: Bool // must be Bool
    let timestamp: Date 
    let base: String
    let rates: [String:Double]
}
```

---

```
var rates = [String:Double]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let jsonUrlString = "https://currencyapi.net/api/v1/rates?key=6b171cc58787d922eb53e3684d97784d165a&base=USD"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
        guard let error = error else { print(error); return }

        do {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
           let result = try decoder.decode(CurrencyRate.self, from: data!)
           self.rates = result.rates
           print(rates)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()   
}
```

`timestamp` is decoded as `Date`